# adding a new node in XML file via PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I just wanted to ask how I can insert a new node in an XML using PHP. my XML file (questions.xml) is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Quiz>
   <topic text="Preparation for Exam">
      <subtopic text="Science" />
      <subtopic text="Maths" />
      <subtopic text="english" />
   </topic>
</Quiz>
```

I want to add a new "subtopic" with the "text" attribute, that is "geography". How can I do this using PHP? Thanks in advance though.
well my code is

```
<?php

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('questions.xml');


$root = $xmldoc->firstChild;

$newElement = $xmldoc->createElement('subtopic');
$root->appendChild($newElement);
// $newText = $xmldoc->createTextNode('geology');
// $newElement->appendChild($newText);

$xmldoc->save('questions.xml');
?>
```

Comment: yup that was me .. no satisfactory reply . .

Comment: Because you didn't expect an explanation but a piece of code you can use. No reason to ask the same question again.

Comment: there was a reason .. see ..i got 2 valid responses after posting it again...so there was a reason for posting it again .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd use [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) for this. It would look somehow like this:

```
// Open and parse the XML file
$xml = simplexml_load_file("questions.xml");
// Create a child in the first topic node
$child = $xml->topic[0]->addChild("subtopic");
// Add the text attribute
$child->addAttribute("text", "geography");
```

You can either display the new XML code with echo or store it in a file.

```
// Display the new XML code
echo $xml->asXML();
// Store new XML code in questions.xml
$xml->asXML("questions.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks man .. now that was a satisfactory and a very good reply . . i appreciate ur effort

Answer (score 5):

The best and safe way is to load your XML document into a PHP DOMDocument object, and then go to your desired node, add a child, and finally save the new version of the XML into a file.

Take a look at the documentation : [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument)

Example of code:

```
// open and load a XML file
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load('your_file.xml');

// Apply some modification
$specificNode = $dom->getElementsByTagName('node_to_catch');
$newSubTopic = $xmldoc->createElement('subtopic');
$newSubTopicText = $xmldoc->createTextNode('geography');
$newSubTopic->appendChild($newSubTopicText);
$specificNode->appendChild($newSubTopic);

// Save the new version of the file
$dom->save('your_file_v2.xml');
```

Comment: okay... i have edited the file ...my codings are there .. but my code is adding the new subtopic at the end ... and its not adding the text attribute :(

Comment: You have to create a new element `$newSubTopic = $xmldoc->createElement('subtopic');`, then create a new text node `$subTopicContent = $xmldoc->createTextNode('geology');`, and finally append the textnode in the new topic element, and then append te new topic element to your desire node.

Comment: Where have you defined `xmldoc` ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use PHP's [Simple XML.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) You have to read the file content, add the node with Simple XML and write the content back.

Comment: yeah ... can u help me with this ... just a hint...i know how to read stuff using simplexml , but don't know how to add a new node using simple xml..